# Checking if value is true when names are similar in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have some columns in a table named "hasMonday", "hasTuesday", "hasWednesday", etc... with boolean values to know if a certain product belongs to a certain day (can appear at more than one day)

Now I'm making a list of days and show the data of the product if it is available (true). Something similar to this:

**Monday** (hasMonday=true)

Data of the product, price, etc.

**Tuesday** (hasTuesday=false)

There is no product for this day

--

I made an array with the days of the week and now I am trying to know it this day has a product. Here is my code so far:

```
 $days= array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday");

          foreach ($days as $day) {

            echo '<div id="$day" class="dayDiv">';
            echo "<h4>$day Products</h4>";
            if ($Product['hasMonday'] = true) {
              // Show the info
            }else{
              // "No info to show" message
          }...
```

As you can see, the above code repeats all the product on each day, so I would appreciate any help to check this using the less steps possible. Something like:

```
foreach ($days as $day) {

    echo '<div id="$day" class="dayDiv">';
    echo "<h4>$day Products</h4>";
    if($Product['has.$day']){
        //show the info
    }else{
        // "No info to show" message
}
```

Not sure if what I wrote is possible but I believe it helps to understand a bit more what I'm trying to get.

Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
if ($Product["has$day"]) {
```

The way you suggested (`if($Product['has.$day']){`) was on the right track, but variables aren't parsed within single quotes, and the concatenation operator (`.`) is not necessary when [interpolating a variable into a string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) like that.

As others have commented, this way won't work in cases where there is any additional string in the key *after* the variable, for example `$Product["$dayIsPresent"]` would not work, because the end of the variable is ambiguous. For cases like these the variable must be [enclosed in brackets](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) to for it to be interpreted properly (e.g. `$Product["{$day}IsPresent"]`). For cases like yours where the variable is the last thing in the string, the brackets aren't necessary, but it doesn't hurt to add them if you prefer to.

If it's possible that in addition to having `true` or `false` values, `$Product['hasMonday']` etc. *may not actually be set*, you can use `!empty` instead of simply evaluating that array key for truthiness.

```
if (!empty($Product["has{$day}"])) {
```

Comment: Is this really possible? how do you call this function?

Comment: I recommend surrounding the variable in curly braces for readability and less bugs when in a string `$Product["has{$day}"]` both work but adding anything after `$day` would break the code without the braces.

Comment: @HiGonz I meant this to replace the line in the code you suggested. I added a bit more explanation to the answer; sorry it was a bit terse initially.

Comment: or `if(isset($Product["has{$day}"]))`

Comment: @Ghost I don't know, I thought it looked like it should always be set to a boolean, and shouldn't display if false.

Comment: @Don'tPanic or maybe `!empty` covers the falsy

Comment: When it's false I'm adding a button to add a product, so the answer given works perfect! Thank you very much